# Use :after with firefox

Tags: css, firefox

The result on chrome and ie10 are work, but not work on firefox.

I would like to add the shadow background at the bottom of div

please take a look on this

http://jsfiddle.net/yokosatan/mv83a/

Here is the code of HTML

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMLZg7HAU1G8n8ZKnOeai4EsUUtwyyWamco2hPHLjFx2Hl2X3mwQ" border="0"/>
   </div>
   <div class="name">Name</div>
</div>
```

And CSS code

```
.box
{
  text-align:center;
  width:105px;
}
.name
{
  font-size:11pt;
  margin-top:8px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.logo
{
  width:105px;
  height:105px;
  background:white;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position:relative;
}
.logo:after
{
  content:url('http://s24.postimg.org/f1dompt4x/shadow_test.png');
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-15px;
  display:block;
  height:15px;
}
.logo img
{
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:85%;
  width:85%;
  max-height:85%;
}
```

Question is how to do the same result as chrome or ie that display.
Additional, it could be other solution that give the same result for all web browsers.

Thank you

Update: I think the cause is that I make display

```
display:table-cell;
```

I change to be display block and it's work, but I want to make logo to be center vertically.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `content: url();` use `content: ' ';` and use `background-image` and it should work for you

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mv83a/1/)

```
.logo:after {
    content:' ';
    height: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    background-image: url('http://s24.postimg.org/f1dompt4x/shadow_test.png');
    position:absolute;
    top: 110px;
    display:block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Edit:

As you had issue using `display: table-cell;`, you can use `display: block;` instead and use `position: absolute;` for the `img` tag and use `top` and `left` with custom values to set the image vertically middle.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mv83a/7/)

Comment: It's work on only one div. but I have many block and it go wrong again. I think the cause is that I make display to be "table-cell". Any suggestion to make element center vertically?

Comment: @user1128331 what you want to do actually? I am not able to get your English correctly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mv83a/3/

I would like to place blocks as the same on jsfiddle. It not work on second row. I think because I make the .box is display:table-cell. So it work bad on firefox.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much :) Do you want to update the code?
Or Can I mark this answer?

Answer (score 0):

use `content` as ""
and add `background`

```
  .logo:after 
   {
      background:url("http://s24.postimg.org/f1dompt4x/shadow_test.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent;
content:"";
position:absolute;
bottom:-15px;
display:block;
height:15px;
width:110px;
   }
```